# React useState setting initial value has no effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my functional component's relevant code to the issue,

How can I set the initial value after some processing of data within useState() hook?

```
const data = props.data ? props.data : {};
const statusOptions = [
  { label: "Active", value: "active" },
  { label: "Inactive", value: "inactive" },
  { label: "Complete", value: "completed" },
];
const defaultStatus = statusOptions.filter(
  option => option.value === data["status"],
)[0];

//This does not work
const [status, setStatusValue] = useState(defaultStatus);
console.log(status); //undefined

//Below works
const [status, setStatusValue] = useState({
  label: "Complete",
  value: "completed",
});
console.log(status); //{label:"Complete",value:"completed"}
```

Comment: your data variable is probably empty. you need to update your status inside a useEffect hook, with props.data as a dependency

Comment: your filter returns an empty array. So the value of `defaultStatus` is undefined as the index 0 of an empty array will be undefined. Do a console.log of `defaultStatus`.

Comment: btw simplar way to do this: `const data = props.data ? props.data : {};` is `const { data = {} } = props;`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal filter doesn't return undefined when I do `console.log()`. I guess the filter function takes some to execute before which set state is already completed.

Comment: No.your props change, there should be multiple console logs every time props change, check the first one. First time the filter is an empty array, then props change, filter now returns values. initialState will be set only once. Put `setStatusValue` in `useEffect` as suggested in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that `props.data.status` is not empty.

If `props.data.status` is empty, the fallback value empty string `''`will ensure that `status` is not undefined.

```
const data = props.data ? props.data : {};

const statusOptions = [
  { label: "Active", value: "active" },
  { label: "Inactive", value: "inactive" },
 { label: "Complete", value: "completed" },
];

const defaultStatus = statusOptions.filter(
  option => option.value === data["status"],
)[0];

const [status, setStatusValue] = useState(defaultStatus || '');


//using effect hooks and deps to execute logic as componentWillMount
    useEffect(() => {
      // check that props.data.status is non-empty and update statusValue
      if (props.data.status !== '') {
         setStatusValue(props.data.status);
      }
    }, [props.data.status]);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are facing the same issue, I think this may help

> The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded.

So, if the data isn't available, we shouldn't render the component as the initialState may be empty and this empty value will remain there for subsequent renders.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use the entire status object in the state, only the value.

In addition, you can use a function to set a default for the status only once:

```
const statusOptions = [
  { label: "Active", value: "active" },
  { label: "Inactive", value: "inactive" },
  { label: "Complete", value: "completed" },
];
const Thing = ({ data }) => {
  const [statusValue, setStatusValue] = useState(() => {
    const currentStatus = statusOptions.find(
      option => option.value === data.status,
    );
    // Default to `completed` if there was no value in the props
    return currentStatus ? currentStatus.value : "completed";
  });
  const status = statusOptions.find(
    option => option.value === statusValue,
  );
  return <div>{JSON.stringify({ data, statusValue, status })}</div>;
};
```

Comment: I actually need the entire object as I am using it within `react-select` component with material-ui customisation. I tried to achieve the same within a `useEffect` hook with `[]` as `deps`, but still couldn't get it to work. btw data comes perfectly alright I have that sorted out.

Comment: The `const status =` line in my answer acquires the current status from the options list by key.